# VBA method to tag or mark a closed Excel document as "renamed"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of Excel documents in a directory. New files are added to the directory all the time, but they need to be renamed using a specific file name pattern (the procedure `RenameFile` below does this). To solve this I have to iterate through all excel documents and rename *only* the documents that haven't been renamed earlier.

The problem is that I can't determine if a file has been renamed already. I have an idea that I should mark/tag the document as "renamed" in some way. Well, it's easy if I open each document and set a Document Property or other hidden variable. But that solution would force me to open each document in the directory to see if the property is defined, and then close it again and move on to next. This is too time consuming...

What I need is a method to tag/mark/flag each renamed document in some way. This tag/mark/flag must be accessible *without* opening the document. Any ideas?

```
Sub RenameExcelFiles(InFolder As String)
    Dim ExcelFile As String

    ExcelFile = Dir(InFolder & "\*.xlsx")

    Do While ExcelFile <> ""
        If Not ExcelFileHasProperty("Is already renamed") Then
            RenameFile ExcelFile  ' My own rename function
            SetExcelFileProperty "Is already renamed" 
        End If
        ' Fetch Next Excel file...
        ExcelFile = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If they have been renamed already won't they have the pattern already? Use Dir to loop the folder and only add to a collection (for example) if pattern not found. Then loop the collection doing your rename. If they had the right pattern you would be processing anyway.

Comment: Well, let's say that the pattern is a persons name "Adam Smith.xlsx". If a file has the filename "My File.xlsx" it has the same pattern, but it's not renamed correctly yet...
Edit: Ah, you mean I should rename all files, even if they have been renamed already... hmm.. I'll think about that :)

Comment: Then yeah as per @Vityata's add a unique identifier to show processed/

Answer (score 1):

Best case scenario solution (that I can think of) - your excel function could be quite unique - e.g. ending on `_renamedYYYYMMMDDHHMMSS`.
Then, simply split the filename by `_` and check whether it contains the word `_renamed*`. Like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim name As String
    name = "someName_renamed2018FEB02122755"

    Dim newName As String
    newName = Split(name, "_")(UBound(Split(name, "_")))

    If InStr(newName, "renamed") Then
        Debug.Print "Document is renamed!"
    End If   

End Sub
```